# How do I add a linked image/gif onto a larger image?

Tags: html, image, navigation, gif

So I'm trying to build a site where the "title page" is basically one big image that takes up the entire screen, and if you scroll down you get to the content beneath it.

My code so far is:

What I'm trying to do is to put two GIFs on the bottom left and right corners of my image, and of which can be clicked to navigate to another page of the site. I'm unsure though of how to put them onto the larger image and how to position them.

Edit: the HTML code I put in my post is not showing to me?

Comment: Could you add the html/css that you have created so far?

Comment: My code so far is: <img src="something" alt="something" width="100%" height="100%"> I don't know why it's not showing in my original post.

Comment: @Theo1290 You should enter and four indent before code section.